# how to called a static class in another class

Tags: java, swing, class, user-interface

hello i have a problem between my combining frame to one class and to another so i created a program that has a JComboBox then if i click once of this it will appear the called class but in my calendar i cant called it out here is my code in calling my Frames in another class

now that is fine but in my Calendar i have an Exception Error i cant called it out because of static ? or i dont know . here is my Class in Calendar .

```
package Patola;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Calendar
{

    static JLabel lblMonth, lblYear;
    static JButton btnPrev, btnNext;
    static JTable tblCalendar;
    static JComboBox cmbYear;
    static JFrame frmMain;
    static Container pane;
    static DefaultTableModel mtblCalendar;
    static JScrollPane stblCalendar;
    static JPanel pnlCalendar;
    static int realYear, realMonth, realDay, currentYear, currentMonth;

    public static void main (String args[]){

        try {UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());}
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
        catch (InstantiationException e) {}
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {}
        catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {}


        frmMain = new JFrame ("Group Cents");
        frmMain.setSize(330, 375); 
        pane = frmMain.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(null);
        frmMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        lblMonth = new JLabel ("January");
        lblYear = new JLabel ("Jump to year :");
        cmbYear = new JComboBox();
        btnPrev = new JButton ("prev");
        btnNext = new JButton ("next");
        mtblCalendar = new DefaultTableModel(){public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int mColIndex){return false;}};
        tblCalendar = new JTable(mtblCalendar);
        stblCalendar = new JScrollPane(tblCalendar);
        pnlCalendar = new JPanel(null);


        pnlCalendar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Calendar"));


        btnPrev.addActionListener(new btnPrev_Action());
        btnNext.addActionListener(new btnNext_Action());
        cmbYear.addActionListener(new cmbYear_Action());


        pane.add(pnlCalendar);
        pnlCalendar.add(lblMonth);
        pnlCalendar.add(lblYear);
        pnlCalendar.add(cmbYear);
        pnlCalendar.add(btnPrev);
        pnlCalendar.add(btnNext);
        pnlCalendar.add(stblCalendar);

        Font font = new Font("Algerian", Font.PLAIN, 14);
        lblMonth.setFont(font);
        lblMonth.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        pnlCalendar.setBounds(0, 0, 320, 335);
        lblMonth.setBounds(160-lblMonth.getPreferredSize().width/2, 25, 100, 25);
        lblYear.setBounds(10, 305, 150, 20);
        cmbYear.setBounds(230, 305, 80, 20);
        btnPrev.setBounds(10, 25, 60, 25);
        btnNext.setBounds(250, 25, 60, 25);
        stblCalendar.setBounds(10, 50, 300, 250);
        pnlCalendar.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        btnPrev.setForeground(Color.RED);
        btnNext.setForeground(Color.RED);
        frmMain.setResizable(false);
        frmMain.setVisible(true);
        lblYear.setFont(font);
        lblYear.setForeground(Color.RED);

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); 
        realDay = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 
        realMonth = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH); 
        realYear = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR); 
        currentMonth = realMonth;
        currentYear = realYear;


        String[] headers = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};

        for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
        {
            mtblCalendar.addColumn(headers[i]);
        }

        tblCalendar.getParent().setBackground(tblCalendar.getBackground());


        tblCalendar.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
        tblCalendar.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);


        tblCalendar.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        tblCalendar.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        tblCalendar.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);


        tblCalendar.setRowHeight(38);
        mtblCalendar.setColumnCount(7);
        mtblCalendar.setRowCount(6);


        for (int i=realYear-100; i<=realYear+100; i++)
        {
            cmbYear.addItem(String.valueOf(i));
        }


        refreshCalendar (realMonth, realYear);
    }

    public static void refreshCalendar(int month, int year){

        String[] months =  {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
        int nod, som; 


        btnPrev.setEnabled(true);
        btnNext.setEnabled(true);
        if (month == 0 && year <= realYear-10){btnPrev.setEnabled(false);} 
        if (month == 11 && year >= realYear+100){btnNext.setEnabled(false);} 
        lblMonth.setText(months[month]); 
        lblMonth.setBounds(160-lblMonth.getPreferredSize().width/2, 25, 180, 25); 
        cmbYear.setSelectedItem(String.valueOf(year));


        for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<7; j++)
            {
                mtblCalendar.setValueAt(null, i, j);
            }
        }


        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
        nod = cal.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        som = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);


        for (int i=1; i<=nod; i++)
        {
            int row = new Integer((i+som-2)/7);
            int column  =  (i+som-2)%7;
            mtblCalendar.setValueAt(i, row, column);
        }


        tblCalendar.setDefaultRenderer(tblCalendar.getColumnClass(0), new tblCalendarRenderer());
    }

    static class tblCalendarRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
    {
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table, Object value, boolean selected, boolean focused, int row, int column)
        {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, selected, focused, row, column);
            if (column == 0 || column == 6)
            { 
                setBackground(new Color(255, 220, 220));
            }
            else
            {
                setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            }
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (Integer.parseInt(value.toString()) == realDay && currentMonth == realMonth && currentYear == realYear)
                { 
                    setBackground(new Color(220, 220, 255));
                }
            }
            setBorder(null);
            setForeground(Color.black);
            return this;
        }
    }

    static class btnPrev_Action implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (currentMonth == 0)
            { 
                currentMonth = 11;
                currentYear -= 1;
            }
            else{ 
                currentMonth -= 1;
            }
            refreshCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
        }
    }
    static class btnNext_Action implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (currentMonth == 11)
            { 
                currentMonth = 0;
                currentYear += 1;
            }
            else
            { 
                currentMonth += 1;
            }
            refreshCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
        }
    }

            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a static variable using an object of Calendar class

```
 new Calendar().frmMain.setVisible(true);
```

while `frmMain` is defined as `static` in `Calendar` class.

If you are sure `frmMain` is already instantiated in `Calendar` class, you can access it using

```
Calendar.frmMain.setVisible(true)
```

Comment: what do i need to do sir ?

Comment: that is my question what do i need to do or what is your suggest to called the static part i cant change it into a non static form sir >.<

Comment: this is the error in Calendar.frmMain.setVisible(true);
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Patola.imagebut$1.actionPerformed(imagebut.java:90)
 at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1260)
 at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:588)
 at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:624)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicComboPopup.java:835)
 at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)

Comment: It seems you haven't instantiated the `frmMain` object and trying to access it's `setVisible` method - which leads to `NullPointerException`

Comment: what do i need to do sir ?

Comment: You really need to work on your Java Basics. There are many things just wrong with your code so don't think that I will just write the complete code for you.